# Python-specific top-down vs bottom-up dynamic programming speed

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to understand two solutions to a tough Leetcode dynamic programming problem [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/burst-balloons/solutions/970727/python-5-lines-dp-explained/?orderBy=most_votes). Two other people came up with answers that have supposedly equivalent time complexities, but one uses top-down and the other bottom-up. The bottom-up solution is consistently about 50% faster for large inputs and therefore gets accepted by Leetcode whereas the top-down solution does not. Why such a big difference?

Does it have to do with cache locality, where a dictionary performs worse than an array? Is it something about the Python decorator that makes it perform worse? I've done many dynamic programming problems on Leetcode, and it seems that bottom-up approaches in Python specifically are often considerably faster than their top-down counterparts.

```
import timeit
from functools import lru_cache

class TopDownSolution:
    def max_coins(self, nums):
        A = [1] + nums + [1]

        @lru_cache(None)
        def dfs(i, j):
            return max([A[i ] *A[k ] *A[j] + dfs(i ,k) + dfs(k ,j) for k in range( i +1, j)] or [0])

        return dfs(0, len(A) - 1)


class BottomUpSolution:
    def max_coins(self, A):
        A, n = [1] + A + [1], len(A) + 2
        dp = [[0] * n for _ in range(n)]

        for i in range(n - 2, -1, -1):
            for j in range(i + 2, n):
                dp[i][j] = max(A[i] * A[k] * A[j] + dp[i][k] + dp[k][j] for k in range(i + 1, j))

        return dp[0][n - 1]

# Takes a long time to run
diabolical_test_case = [100] * 300

# Bottom up: 15.349703255
bottom_up = BottomUpSolution()
print(f'Bottom up: {timeit.timeit(lambda: bottom_up.max_coins(diabolical_test_case), number=10)}')

# Top down: 25.657852577
top_down = TopDownSolution()
print(f'Top down: {timeit.timeit(lambda: top_down.max_coins(diabolical_test_case), number=10)}')
```

Comment: Accessing/assigning to a list element is relatively cheap (in Python, O(1)) whereas a function call not necessarily (see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180919031245/https://plus.google.com/115212051037621986145/posts/HajXHPGN752): _"Be suspicious of function/method calls; creating a stack frame is expensive."_?